# How to compare in terms of ether with chai?

Tags: typescript, solidity, chai, ethers.js, hardhat

I have tried comparing a couple ways. I really wanted to compare in ETH terms. I have tried using formatEther but it returns a string. How can I compare this easily in terms of ETH?

```
    const ownerBal = await ethers.provider.getBalance(accounts[0].address);
    expect(BigNumber.from(ownerBal)).to.be.closeTo(
      BigNumber.from(1000),
      BigNumber.from(1)
    );
```

Comment: What are you testing? The purpose of testing is to apply some operation and see the operation behaves as expected or not

Comment: I was testing my withdraw method in my nft contract. I didnt understand why ether was returns as a big number or a string. Both were usable by the expect function unless i wanted to work in wei. @Yilmaz

Answer (score 0):

I ended up parsing the float from the string. To then round it and compare it as a number.

```
async function formatBalance(
  address: string,
  fractionDigits: number
): Promise<number> {
  const bn = await ethers.provider.getBalance(address);
  const bal = formatEther(bn);
  return parseFloat(parseFloat(bal).toFixed(fractionDigits));
}

const contractBalNew = await formatBalance(contractA.address, 2);
expect(contractBalNew).to.be.equal(0);
expect(contractBalNew).to.be.within(10003, 10004);
```